# How do you get post value in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Customer controller that has these 2 action methods.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(IFormCollection form)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I also created a Customer view.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/Customer/Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">FirstName *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="FirstName">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">LastName *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="LastName">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

How do I get the post values? Every time I submit the form it goes to the `[HttpGet]` and I want to use the `[HttpPost]`. I'm new to ASP.NET Core so sorry for the simple question.

Comment: You cannot have two methods with the same name and identically-typed parameters, as in your example: it will not even compile.

Comment: Your right I forgot I added this parameter. I was trying to minimize my code to post it here. IFormCollection form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add 2 parameter to your http post action method which is matching with your form element **names**.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(string firstName,string lastName)
{
    return View();
}
```

Another option is to create view model class with properties matching to form element names. This is useful when you have many input elements in the form and do not want to add clutter to the parameter list of your action method.

```
public class LoginVm
{
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  public string LastName { set;get;}
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(LoginVm model)
{
    // to do : user model.FirstName and model.LastName
    return View();
}
```

When the form is submitted, the model binder will read the posted form data and map it to the view model object property values.

Remember, view model is specific to the view. So if your view(form) is sending 5 fields, create a simple POCO view model with only those 5 fields.

Comment: I have more input than that. I just only added those to keep my question short. I would like a way that retrieve all inputs in request body.

Comment: You should use the second approach, creating a view model to handle the form post. that is the clean way to handle it.

Answer (score 11):

Several ways:

- Add a `FirstName` and `LastName` (case insensitive) string parameter to the `Create` method that accepts a post
- Add a parameter of type `IFormCollection` to this same method and access the named values `FirstName` and `LastName`
- Directly access the values from `HttpContext.Request.Form`
- Access the values from the `ModelState` property
- Add a model parameter of a POCO class that holds whatever values you want to submit

Comment: when I add the IFormCollection parameter my form doesn't hit the [HttpPost] it only goes to the [HttpGet]. How to I make my html form go to the [HttpPost]?

Comment: Can you add an `[ActionName("Index")]` attribute to the `Create` method that is callable by GET?